# Processing game restart not working

Tags: java

Hello guys I'm trying to implement a restart function but its not working I would like to know if u could help me find a good way to restart this game.

```
World world;
PImage space;

void setup()
{
  size(800,600);
  space = loadImage("SpaceBuracos.jpg");
  space.resize(800,600);
  world = new World(8);
}

void draw()
{
  background(space);
  if(world.run()){restart();} //if boolean == true restarts the game

}

void restart(){
  world =  new World(8);
}
```

`world = new world(8);` creates 8 planets, but when i `restart()` the game itself resets but non of the planets appear.

I would like to completely kill the previews game and start anew but I dunno if it can be done.

Comment: So explain what happens

Comment: where is your main function? where is the game loop? where are you calling setup, draw and restart?

Comment: This is the main class that creates the world, and then the world creates all of the following ones. i did not put all the code here cuz its kinda big.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII This is Processing. Look at the Processing documentation- `setup()` is the main method.

Comment: yap setup is the main like in java. I do know that, the problem is reseting the previews game